# Angular2 - Delete Row Or Column Where the delete button was clicked

Tags: jquery, angular, angular2-template

We can easily delete something like that using jquery, but can we use angular to do something like this?

```
<tr>
<td *ngFor="#lev of rubric?.criteria[0].levels">
                    <button class="close removeLevel" (click)="onClickRemove($event)">&times;</button>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Performance Level"
                           #level="ngForm"
                           [(ngModel)]="lev.level"
                           ngControl="level"
                    />
</td>
</tr>
```

And in Component.ts:

```
onClickRemove($event) {
}
```

How can I access the row or cell element here, from where the event was raised?

Comment: For Future Viewers this is my final code:
onClickRemove($event) {
        var node = $event.target.parentNode;
        var index =  node.cellIndex - 1;
        for(let i = 0; i < this.rubric.criteria.length; i++) {
            this.rubric.criteria[0].levels.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From you question , you want to delete the row when the delete button is pressed . 
In Angular way what you must be doing is to remove the record from the model . So for that just pass the row id for something that unique to the ng-controller  and remove it from the model.

So if you have something like below

```
 <td *ngFor="#lev of rubric?.criteria[0].levels">
                    <button class="close removeLevel" ng-click="onClickRemove($index)">&times;</button>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Performance Level"
                           #level="ngForm"
                           [(ngModel)]="lev.level"
                           ngControl="level"
                    />
</td>
```

in controller

```
$scope.onClickRemove=function(index)
{
   //Replace your model here 
   rows.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The beauty of using a change detection framework like Angular is that you only need to modify your models, and your views are automatically updated.  There is no need to modify the DOM yourself.

Here's how it works:

- Angular uses [Zone.js](https://github.com/angular/zone.js/) to monkey patch (intercept) all of the browser's asynchronous events (like mouse clicks), that occur inside Angular.  So any event bindings we put in our components will be monkey patched.
- Angular builds a component tree, and each node in the tree also has a change detector object (you can get a reference to it by injecting [`ChangeDetectorRef`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef-class.html)).  It keeps track of all of your view bindings, and it remembers the last value of each binding.
- When an event fires, your event handler/callback function executes.  When it finishes, because of the Zone.js monkey patching, it then calls Angular's change detection algorithm.  That algorithm walks the tree (once) and looks for changes using those change detector objects.  If it finds any changes, it updates the component if necessary (e.g., if an input property changed), and then updates the DOM.
- Change detection ends, the browser gets control again, sees the DOM changes and updates what you see on the screen.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. It really helped me understand the angular2 change detection system. I wasn't sure if the DOM is updated after every event.